# What am I doing wrong for this setup? Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

Hey so I am trying to get this Backbone.js example going... This is the original files for a todo project:

main.js file

```
(function() {

    window.App = {
        Models: {},
        Collections: {},
        Views: {},
        Router: {}
        //Routes, Templates
    };

    //App.Helpers = {};
    //App.Helpers.template = ...
    window.template = function(id) {
        return _.template($('#' + id).html());
    }

    App.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {

        }
    });

    App.Models.Task = Backbone.Model.extend({
        default: {
            title: '',
            completed: false
        },

    });



    App.Views.Task = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'p',

        template: template('taskTemplate'),

        initialize: function() {
            this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
            this.model.on('destroy', this.remove, this);
        },

        events: {
            'click .edit': 'editTask',
            'click .delete': 'destroy',
            'click .checked': 'checked'
        },

        editTask: function() {
            var newTaskTitle = prompt('wata change to', this.model.get('title'));
            this.model.set('title', newTaskTitle);

            if(!newTaskTitle) return;
            this.model.set('title', newTaskTitle);
        },
        destroy: function() {
            this.model.destroy();
        },

        render: function() {
            var template = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
            this.$el.html(template);
            return this;
        },

        remove: function() {
            this.$el.remove();
        },

        checked: function() {
            console.log(this.$el.hasClass('taskComplete'));
            if( $('.checked:checked') && !this.$el.hasClass('taskComplete')) {
                this.$el.addClass('taskComplete');

            } else {
                this.$el.removeClass('taskComplete');
            }
        }


    });



    App.Collections.Tasks = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: App.Models.Task
    });


    App.Views.Tasks = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'ul',

        initialize: function() {
            this.collection.on('add', this.addOne, this)
        },

        render: function() {
            this.collection.each(this.addOne, this);

            return this;
        },

        addOne: function(task) {
            var taskView = new App.Views.Task({model: task});
            this.$el.append(taskView.render().el);
        }

    });

    App.Views.AddTask = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '#addtask',

        events: {
            'submit': 'submit'
        },

        initialize: function() {

        },

        submit:function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var newTaskTitle = $(e.currentTarget).find('input[type=text]').val();

            var task = new App.Models.Task({title: newTaskTitle});
            console.log(this.collection);
            this.collection.add(task);
        }
    });


    var tasks = new App.Collections.Tasks ([
        {
            title: 'Go to the store',
            priority: 4
        },
        {
            title: 'Go to the mall',
            priority: 3
        },
        {
            title: 'Go to work',
            priority: 5
        },
    ]);
        var addTaskView = new App.Views.AddTask({collection: tasks });

    var tasksView = new App.Views.Tasks({collection: tasks});
    $('.tasks').html(tasksView.render().el);

}) ();
```

This is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <style>
        .taskComplete {
            text-decoration: line-through;
        }
    </style>
    <h1> My Tasks </h1>
    <form id="addtask" action="">
        <input type="text" placeholder="new task">
        <input type="submit" value="Add Task">
    </form>
    <div class="tasks">

        <script id='taskTemplate' type='text/template'>
            <input class='checked' type="checkbox">
            <span> <%= title %> </span>
            <button class='edit'> Edit </button>
            <button class='delete'> Delete </button>

        </script>

    </div>

    <script src="js/underscore.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/backbone.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to separate them into separate files with require.js like this: (named it user so it is easier to differentiate between other file)

Here is the template file: user.html

```
<input class='checked' type="checkbox">
<span> <%= title %> </span>
<button class='edit'> Edit </button>
<button class='delete'> Delete </button>
```

Here is the /models/user.js

```
define([
  'underscore',
  'backbone'
], function(_, Backbone) {

  var user = Backbone.Model.extend({
        default: {
            title: '',
            completed: false
        },

    });
  return user;
});
```

Here is the user collection /collections/user

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'models/user'

], function($, _, Backbone, userM){

    var users = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: userM
  });

  return users;
});
```

Here is the user view:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  // Pull in the Collection module from above,
  'models/user'
  'text!templates/user.html'

], function($, _, Backbone, userM, userT){
  var user = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'p',

    template: template('taskTemplate'),

    initialize: function() {
      this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
      this.model.on('destroy', this.remove, this);
    },

    events: {
      'click .edit': 'editTask',
      'click .delete': 'destroy',
      'click .checked': 'checked'
    },

    editTask: function() {
      var newTaskTitle = prompt('wata change to', this.model.get('title'));
      this.model.set('title', newTaskTitle);

      if(!newTaskTitle) return;
      this.model.set('title', newTaskTitle);
    },
    destroy: function() {
      this.model.destroy();
    },

    render: function() {
      var template = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
      this.$el.html(template);
      return this;
    },

    remove: function() {
      this.$el.remove();
    },

    checked: function() {
      console.log(this.$el.hasClass('taskComplete'));
      if( $('.checked:checked') && !this.$el.hasClass('taskComplete')) {
        this.$el.addClass('taskComplete');

      } else {
        this.$el.removeClass('taskComplete');
      }
    }


  });
  return user;
});
```

Here is the users view:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  // Pull in the Collection module from above,
  'models/user',
  'views/user',
  'collections/users',
  'text!templates/user.html'

], function($, _, Backbone, userM, userV, userC){
  var users = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',

    initialize: function() {
      this.collection.on('add', this.addOne, this)
    },

    render: function() {
      this.collection.each(this.addOne, this);

      return this;
    },

    addOne: function(userM) {
      var userView = new userV({model: userM});
      this.$el.append(userView.render().el);
    }
    return users;
  });
});
```

Here is the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <style>
        .taskComplete {
            text-decoration: line-through;
        }
    </style>
    <h1> My Tasks </h1>
    <form id="addtask" action="">
        <input type="text" placeholder="new task">
        <input type="submit" value="Add Task">
    </form>
    <div class="tasks">

    </div>

    <script src="js/libs/underscore.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/backbone.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/require.js"></script>
    <script src="js/views/users.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong when I am trying to separate the files...

Comment: What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: Sorry for the second one, I am basically trying to set up the second part  (the separate files) with require.js correctly, so instead of having the model, view, collections and etc all in one file... but for some reason only the html is rendering... without the view changes from backbone